# Cannot find module generated with “Ionic g provider”

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I generated a provider in Ionic CLI as below:

> C:\Ionic\myApp>ionic g provider DataService
>
> [OK] Generated a provider named DataService!

However, when I try to import that in app.module.ts as below:

```js
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { DataService } from '../providers/data-service';
```

I get an error saying

> Cannot find module '../providers/data-service'

app.module.ts is located @ *src/app/app.module.ts* and the path '*../providers/data-service*' to data service is correct from its location.

Can anyone please suggest where am I going wrong here?

I am trying to build the exercise given in : https://www.djamware.com/post/58fdf9f080aca7414e78a63a/ionic-3-and-angular-4-multi-level-accordion-menu-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path should include the file name as well without `.ts`:

```
import { DataServiceProvider } from '../providers/data-service/data-service';
```

But normally `ionic g` does this for you, unless you used the `--no-module` option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I try that I get the below error >
message: 'Module '"c:/Ionic/myApp/src/providers/data-service/data-service"' has no exported member 'DataService'.'
at: '14,10'
source: 'ts'

Comment: data-service.ts `import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the DataServiceProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class DataServiceProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello DataServiceProvider Provider');
  }
  
  getmenus(){
    return this.http.get('assets/data/menus.json')
    .map((response:Response)=>response.json());
  }
}`

Comment: The name of the provider is DataServiceProvider. I updated my answer with that.

Comment: DataServiceProvider is already available as default. I created a provider named "DataService" in step-1, is that what I should import?